# How to fill an activity with either checkbox or radiogroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an app that would ask the user questions and the user would select answer(s) and click the button to submit the answer(s). The answers can be in form of checkboxes or radiogroup to make it fun. However, I've got trouble figuring out how it will be possible to fill an activity with one of them based on how the answer is designed.

To pose the question, I can use a TextView; all good there. But how would I change the second view to checkboxes or radiogroup based on the type of answer I'm expecting? As a beginner, I've learnt how to make use of different views, but haven't come across such a case.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably make a `Question` class. Have it hold a `boolean` or `enum` value of the type of question

Comment: `enum` is definitely more suitable as it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewSwitcher

**layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ViewSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/button_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk_android"
        android:checked="true" />

  <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male"
            android:checked="true" />

</ViewSwitcher>
```

**Activity class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ViewSwitcher);

    Button Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_checkbox);
    Button Previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_radio);
```

To navigate through the views use showNext() or showPrevious() methods

```
switcher.showNext();    
switcher.showPrevious();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!